# Java EE Clarification on Workflow for JSP and Servlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am attempting to learn Java EE. After struggling through trying to understand the Java stack, it appears that that a basic dynamic web application can be accomplished by focusing on JSP and Servlets so I want to start there.

In Net Beans I have a basic project set up with a tomcat server and when I hit run I can get the web page to generate and display the default index.jsp page. I have added a css file to the project and this jsp page looks like any standard html page now.  I then create a new servlet. I was also able to create a link in the index.jsp page so when I click on it, it calls the servlet.

What I don't understand is why when I create the servlet in Net Beans, the processRequest method comes pre-populated with several html print statements. I could easily make this page look like the jsp page I started with, making me wonder why I even need a JSP page. It appears the entire application could be comprised of servlets.

Could someone please explain the proper interaction between the two? It appears the index page can contain links that call various servlets, perhaps to access a database of comments, then do I create the response table in the servlet, or would I pass that information to another JSP page?

Understanding these basic workflows would really help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP also a kind of a servlet . Right after you run the jsp , go to your netbeans project directory and right click the jsp and select **view Servlet** then you get the servlet representation of your jsp file. Actually jsp file is there to perform front end design easily. Without jsp It is really difficult task to perform front-end developing stuff inside servlet. 
And you should keep in mind there is no such a thing called `proccessRequest` in javaEE . It is automatically generated by Netbeans once you create a new servlet. So just stick to basics. Erase all the auto-generated stuff from the class which has extended `HttpServlet`. And then you can override the required HTTP method/methods. (doGet , doPost etc..) You should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2097732/5454585) for more infromation ...

And this [page](https://servlets.zeef.com/bauke.scholtz) will also improve your knowledge on javaEE

Comment: Thanks for those additional links. That helped as well as your response.